# C# EF автоматическая загрузка связанных данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется 2 таблицы, между ними связь многие-ко-многим :

```
public class Film
{
    public Film()
    {
        Actors_FIlm = new List<Actors>();
    }
    [Key]   
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //Какие-то данные
    public virtual ICollection<Actors> Actors_FIlm { get; set; }
}

public class Actors
{
    public Actors()
    {
        Films = new List<Film>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Film> Films { get; set; }
}
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, что бы связанные данные автоматически подгружались или мне это нужно всегда самому делать?

Comment: У вас Code-First?

Comment: @Anamnian именно.

Comment: Сейчас данные подгружаются при обращении к навигационному свойству? А вы как хотите?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Когда я возвращаю объект List<Film> с функции и работаю с этим объектом где-то в другой сборке, оказывается, что Actors_Film пусто.

Comment: Вам лучше не делать в данном случае автоматическую загрузку всех навигационных свойств, т.к. произойдет зацикливание подгрузок этих свойств.

Comment: @АндрейNOP К примеру у меня есть 'DbSet<Film> Films' . Когда я пишу 'return Films.ToList();' то свойство Actors_Film пусто.

Comment: Нужно делать Include(w => w.Actors_Film) если нужно загрузить и актёров,

Comment: @SultanovShamil Та, это именно то, что мне нужно было.

Comment: @SultanovShamil а если мне нужно загрузить два свойства... Скажем актёры и их авторы?

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000 можно писать Include(w => w.Actors_Film).Include(w => w.Authors)
Если нужно загрузить свойство из Actors_Film, то нужно скачать доп. пакет ThenInclude (если используете EF6, для EFCore не нужно) и можно сделать так: Include(w => w.Actors_Film).ThenInclude(w => w.Authors)

Comment: @SultanovShamil Почему бы Вам не написать полноценный ответ? :-)

Comment: Вообще, связь многие-ко-многим нежелательна и её принято разбивать третьей, связующей таблицей.

Comment: @Jagailo Так-с такая таблица как раз-таки присуствует

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000 Окей, видимо EF теперь всё сам делает...

Comment: @Jagailo xе-хе, да, EF сам создал с моего кода такую таблицу.)